# Is there a better way to compare errors in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this error:

```
public enum AuthenticationError: Error {
    case unknownError
    case canceledByUser
    case userOrPasswordMismatch
    case unableToExtractOneTimeCode
    case unableToExchangeOneTimeCodeForToken
    case credentialsUnavailable
    case expired
    case webRequestFailed(error: Error)
}
```

I'd like to overload `==` to compare it but I find I need to repeat the code three ways:

```
public func == (lhs: Error, rhs: AuthenticationError) -> Bool {
   return lhs._code == rhs._code && lhs._domain == rhs._domain
}

public func == (lhs: AuthenticationError, rhs: Error) -> Bool
public func == (lhs: AuthenticationError, rhs: AuthenticationError) -> Bool
```

An usage example is:

```
if let error = error, error == AuthenticationError.expired {
   // do something
}
```

Is there a better way to do this (with generics) so I don't need to repeat similar code?

Comment: Why do you need all those == operators, how would you use them?  (There are other ways to compare a general Error against a specific AuthenticationError.)

Comment: All that `Error` can do is provide a `localizedDescription`. You most certainly don't want to establish equality between objects based on a human description (let alone a localized one!), so what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your usage example cannot be a good reason why you need equality for your error type. `if let authError = error as? AuthenticationError, case .expired = authError {...}` would do the same thing as expected. Find a better example, or change your mind.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This suffices for your `.expired` check, without needing to define `==`:

```
let error: Error = ...
if case AuthenticationError.expired = error {
    print("it's expired")
}
```

If you want to extract associated data (as in the `.webRequestFailed` case), you can do this:

```
if case AuthenticationError.webRequestFailed(error: let innerError) = error {
    print("web request failed due to \(innerError.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Here's my macOS playground, created in Xcode 9.2:

```
import Foundation

public enum AuthenticationError: Error {
    case unknownError
    case canceledByUser
    case userOrPasswordMismatch
    case unableToExtractOneTimeCode
    case unableToExchangeOneTimeCodeForToken
    case credentialsUnavailable
    case expired
    case webRequestFailed(error: Error)
}

func test(_ error: Error) {
    if case AuthenticationError.expired = error {
        print("it's expired; error = \(error)")
    } else if case AuthenticationError.webRequestFailed(error: let innerError) = error {
        print("web request failed due to \(innerError.localizedDescription); error = \(error)")
    } else {
        print("no match; error = \(error)")
    }
}

test(AuthenticationError.expired)
test(AuthenticationError.webRequestFailed(error: AuthenticationError.credentialsUnavailable))
test(NSError(domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code: Int(ENOENT), userInfo: [:]))
```

Comment: Found that I was testing if-case without unwrapping `Optional<Error>`, thanks for giving me back kind responses. I will remove wrong comments later.

Comment: Thx. I've removed the overload and went something based on your suggestions above and feedback from @oope. Works great.

Answer (score 12):

### Details

- Swift 5.1
- Xcode 11.6 (11E708)

### Solution

```
public func == (lhs: Error, rhs: Error) -> Bool {
    guard type(of: lhs) == type(of: rhs) else { return false }
    let error1 = lhs as NSError
    let error2 = rhs as NSError
    return error1.domain == error2.domain && error1.code == error2.code && "\(lhs)" == "\(rhs)"
}

extension Equatable where Self : Error {
    public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs as Error == rhs as Error
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
enum MyError: Error { case problem, bigProblem, catastrophicException }
enum MyError2: Error, Equatable { case oops, RUUUUUN(where: String) }

var errors = [Error]()
errors.append(MyError.problem)
errors.append(MyError.catastrophicException)
errors.append(MyError2.oops)
errors.append(MyError2.RUUUUUN(where: "I don't know"))
errors.append(MyError2.RUUUUUN(where: "No matter!!!"))
errors.append(NSError(domain: "domain", code: 234, userInfo: nil))
errors.append(NSError(domain: "domain2", code: 345, userInfo: nil))

for i in 0..<errors.count {
    for j in i..<errors.count {
        print("==============================================")
        print("Error1: \(errors[i])")
        print("Error2: \(errors[j])")
        let result = errors[i] == errors[j]
        print("(Error1 == Error2) = \(result ? "✅" : "❌" ) ")
    }
}
```

### Console

```
==============================================
Error1: problem
Error2: problem
(Error1 == Error2) = ✅ 
==============================================
Error1: problem
Error2: catastrophicException
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: problem
Error2: oops
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: problem
Error2: RUUUUUN(where: "I don\'t know")
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: problem
Error2: RUUUUUN(where: "No matter!!!")
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: problem
Error2: Error Domain=domain Code=234 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: problem
Error2: Error Domain=domain2 Code=345 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: catastrophicException
Error2: catastrophicException
(Error1 == Error2) = ✅ 
==============================================
Error1: catastrophicException
Error2: oops
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: catastrophicException
Error2: RUUUUUN(where: "I don\'t know")
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: catastrophicException
Error2: RUUUUUN(where: "No matter!!!")
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: catastrophicException
Error2: Error Domain=domain Code=234 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: catastrophicException
Error2: Error Domain=domain2 Code=345 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: oops
Error2: oops
(Error1 == Error2) = ✅ 
==============================================
Error1: oops
Error2: RUUUUUN(where: "I don\'t know")
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: oops
Error2: RUUUUUN(where: "No matter!!!")
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: oops
Error2: Error Domain=domain Code=234 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: oops
Error2: Error Domain=domain2 Code=345 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: RUUUUUN(where: "I don\'t know")
Error2: RUUUUUN(where: "I don\'t know")
(Error1 == Error2) = ✅ 
==============================================
Error1: RUUUUUN(where: "I don\'t know")
Error2: RUUUUUN(where: "No matter!!!")
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: RUUUUUN(where: "I don\'t know")
Error2: Error Domain=domain Code=234 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: RUUUUUN(where: "I don\'t know")
Error2: Error Domain=domain2 Code=345 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: RUUUUUN(where: "No matter!!!")
Error2: RUUUUUN(where: "No matter!!!")
(Error1 == Error2) = ✅ 
==============================================
Error1: RUUUUUN(where: "No matter!!!")
Error2: Error Domain=domain Code=234 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: RUUUUUN(where: "No matter!!!")
Error2: Error Domain=domain2 Code=345 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: Error Domain=domain Code=234 "(null)"
Error2: Error Domain=domain Code=234 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ✅ 
==============================================
Error1: Error Domain=domain Code=234 "(null)"
Error2: Error Domain=domain2 Code=345 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ❌ 
==============================================
Error1: Error Domain=domain2 Code=345 "(null)"
Error2: Error Domain=domain2 Code=345 "(null)"
(Error1 == Error2) = ✅
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

You just need to inherit `Equatable` protocol for your enum to make it comparable e.g.:

```
enum MyError: Error, Equatable {
    case unknown
    case canceled
    case expired
}

let err1 = MyError.unknown
let err2 = MyError.canceled
let err3 = MyError.canceled
print("err1 == err2 - \(err1 == err2)")
print("err2 == err3 - \(err2 == err3)")


Prints:

err1 == err2 - false
err2 == err3 - true
```

But in your case you have `Error` in associated value so that you get next error:

```
public enum AuthenticationError: Error, Equatable {
...
}
// error: type 'AuthenticationError' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
// note: associated value type 'Error' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable', preventing synthesized conformance of 'AuthenticationError' to 'Equatable'
```

Thats because `Error` protocol do not conform to `Equatable` and we can't extend one protocol with the other:

```
extension Error: Equatable { 
}
// error: Extension of `protocol` cant have inheritance clause
```

To fix this let's create a error wrapper that conforms to `Equatable` and compares your errors by reflecting strings:

```
public struct ErrorWrapper: Equatable {
    let error: Error
    
    public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        String(reflecting: lhs.error) == String(reflecting: rhs.error)
    }
}

public enum AuthenticationError: Error, Equatable {
    case unknownError
    case canceledByUser
    case userOrPasswordMismatch
    case unableToExtractOneTimeCode
    case unableToExchangeOneTimeCodeForToken
    case credentialsUnavailable
    case expired
    case webRequestFailed(ErrorWrapper)
}

let err1 = AuthenticationError.unknownError
let err2 = AuthenticationError.webRequestFailed(ErrorWrapper(error: error))
let err3 = AuthenticationError.webRequestFailed(ErrorWrapper(error: error))
print("err1 == err2 - \(err1 == err2)")
print("err2 == err3 - \(err2 == err3)")

Prints:

err1 == err2 - false
err2 == err3 - true
```

Comment: String(reflecting: lhs.error) == String(reflecting: rhs.error)  

Answer (score 0):

I got an error, "Enum case ... is not a member of type ...", with the if-case in Xcode v12.1 and Swift 5. It seems the best to use switch-case statement. It also can prevent an unhandled case.

```
public enum AuthenticationError: Error {
    case unknownError
    case canceledByUser
    case userOrPasswordMismatch
    case unableToExtractOneTimeCode
    case unableToExchangeOneTimeCodeForToken
    case credentialsUnavailable
    case expired
    case webRequestFailed(error: Error)
}

switch error {
case .expired:
    print("It is expired.")
default:
    print("other error: \(error)")
}
```